# React mapDispatchToProps Object Action Doesn't Work

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this Action

```
export const UserIsLoggedIn = isLoggedIn => (
    { type: types.USER_IS_LOGGED_IN, isLoggedIn });
```

this actionConstant

```
export const USER_IS_LOGGED_IN = "USER_IS_LOGGED_IN";
```

index.js like this

```
import { UserIsLoggedIn } from "./redux/actions";


getUser = () => {
    this.authService.getUser().then(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.props.UserIsLoggedIn(true);
       }
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  UserIsLoggedIn
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (Index);
```

so eventually with above code I get this.props.UserIsLoggedIn is not a function error, if I do `UserIsLoggedIn(true);` nothing happens... I don't quite understand where the problem is..

within the redux chrome extension I can dispatch with below without an error:

```
{
type: "USER_IS_LOGGED_IN", isLoggedIn : true
}
```

below is generally how index looks like

```
const store = configureStore();

class Index extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.getUser();
  }

  getUser = () => {
    this.authService.getUser().then(user => {
      if (user) {
        console.log(this.props.isUserLoggedIn);
        toastr.success("Welcome " + user.profile.given_name);
      } else {
        this.authService.login();
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Route path="/" exact component={App} />
          <Route path="/:type" component={App} />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
      isUserLoggedIn : state.User.isLoggedIn
    }
  }

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  UserIsLoggedIn
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (Index);

ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById("root"));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Note: Another aspect, mapStateToProps is not working either....

Comment: My guess is that mapDispatchToProps must be a function `() => ({ UserIsLoggedIn })`

Comment: @MikeBoutin No, react-redux supports an [object](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object) for `mapDispatchToProps`.

Comment: It would be helpful to see a syntactically complete version of index.js. You're passing `Index` to connect, but that doesn't exist in the code you've shown. `this` is referenced in `getUser`, but you haven't shown any class that it is a part of.

Comment: Another aspect is that, I can't even get values from store with `function mapStateToProps(state) { return { isUserLoggedIn : state.User.isLoggedIn } }` and attempting to write it into console by `console.log(this.props.isUserLoggedIn);` even if I change mapStateToProps to `isUserLoggedIn : state` I get undefined...

Comment: @RyanCogswell I just added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Yusufali2205 and @RyanCogswell for your help but those didn't fix the problem..

For people looking for an answer on this:
index.js is the first file in my React to load then App.js. With this setup, I have `<Provider store={store}>` inside index.js and inside index.js I don't have an access to the store within render method OR any lifecycles such as willmount or even didmount or willunmount. To access store, create it with `<Provider store={store}>` inside index.js and access store items within App.js.

About Dispatching action error, I still get `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type, isLoggedIn}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.` error if I try to dispatch within render method with this code `{this.props.UserIsLoggedIn(true)}`.. I was attempting to do this just to see if dispatching worked, I don't plan to have it actually inside render. When I wrapped it with console.log, it worked fine, like this `{console.log(this.props.UserIsLoggedIn(true))}`..

When I moved these dispatchers to under a lifecycle method, they worked fine without console.log wrapper... like this

```
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log(this.props.isUserLoggedIn)
    this.props.UserIsLoggedIn(true)
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

`<Provider store={store}>` needs to be wrapped around wherever this exported component is used. It can't be within the `render` method of `Index`. The way it is now, the `connect` method won't have access to your `store`.

You need something like:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><Index /></Provider>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

and then remove the `Provider` portion from the `render` method in `Index`:

```
  render() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Route path="/" exact component={App} />
          <Route path="/:type" component={App} />
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to dispatch your action

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  UserIsLoggedIn: (value) => {
    dispatch(UserIsLoggedIn(value));
  }
});
```

Update:
If you want to use the object syntax you need to wrap that action in a funciton:

```
 const mapDispatchToProps = {
  UserIsLoggedIn: (value) => UserIsLoggedIn(value),
};
```

Comment: I do it by defining mapDispatchToProps as object, like here https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object